# Can i use function 't' directly from i18n instance?

Tags: react-i18next

I'm trying to use `react-i18next` library.

Usual way to put function `t` to your component is decorate it with HOC `translate` as said in [docs](https://react.i18next.com/components/translate-hoc.html#translate-hoc).

But anyway you must create an instance of i18n like [this](https://react.i18next.com/components/i18next-instance.html#i18next-instance).

And I can import this instance to my component `import i18n from './i18n'` and then use function `t` like this `i18n.t('namespace:key')`

In this approach I don't need a HOC. Are there any pitfalls that may appear?

Answer (score 2):

the hoc (or render props) do more than just passing down the `t` function to your component - they also assert those namespaces get loaded via backend plugin and depending on setting wait to render your component until the translations are ready.

If you pass in translations via options.resources or using a webpack bundler or similar - the hoc component is not needed.